# IE error when downloading the file from the server

Tags: http, browser

When I am tried to download a file from the server in IE8 I am getting following error:-

> Internet Explorer cannot download file
>   from server.
>
> Internet Explorer was not able to open
>   this Internet site. The requested site
>   is either unavailable or cannot be
>   found. Please try again later.

I am checked in FF also and its working properly.

Please help me...

Comment: This is one of the feature of MS' modern IE :P

Comment: So what will be solution for this problem.

Comment: http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~aakash/cs296.html#cred see this and take decision yourself, sorry for not having actual solution .

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling "prompt for file download" in options>security>zone where the file is(intranet/internet...)